# Copying database from one server to another server in sql server 2014 using wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to copy a database from one server to another server in sql server 2014 using wizard.

Everything is working fine except the last step where the whole process fails because the process fails to execute sql server agent job. 
[Erroneous result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKVDE.png)

In Microsoft document it has been mentioned that to overcome this one needs to create a shell database at the destination server and then select the option **Drop any database on the destination server with the same name, then continue with the database transfer, overwriting existing database files.** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hcbF.png)

So I have created a database of the same name at the destination server and continued but faced the same error again (fails to execute sql server agent job).

Please help the way to overcome it.

Comment: Just do a backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to do a backup from the source server and restore the database on the destination server.  It's much faster than the copy database wizard.

Make sure that if you're using full recovery mode or incremental/differential backups that the backup you take is a COPY ONLY backup.  That will prevent it from breaking the backup chain.

Additionally, you may need to set the destination database to single user mode before you do the drop and restore if you have an application that's going to be connected to the destination database when you want to run the restore.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but If I want to perform it with wizard, then what should be the steps. Please tell me in details. I want to do this because of insufficient permission to do a backup from the source server and restore the database on the destination server

Comment: @DebadritoSaha I can't really help you there other than to point you to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard). I haven't tried to use the Wizard in the last decade.  Backup and restore is faster and more reliable, and I've never had a situation that demanded the wizard (i.e., need to migrate server logins).  If I had a legitimate business need to copy a DB, I'd request proper access to do a backup and restore.  I think you'll find similar answers elsewhere on the web.